# Using a batch file to open Task Manager

Tags: windows, batch-file

Basically I want to use a batch file to open Task Manager.

All I need it to do is open Task Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, just type in `TaskMgr` in Notepad then save as a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

Easy, just type in `TaskMgr.exe` in Notepad then save as a batch file.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer - but maybe it would help to provide some clarification, in this specific case. The question already has an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23815146/12567365). Your answer is _almost_ identical to that answer. Do you _need_ to include the `.exe` suffix? If so, then why? Or, are there any specific advantages to your solution - and, if so, what are they?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask]. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).