# How do I make a batch file that opens Task Manager?

Tags: batch-file, process

So i have been looking for this on this website and cannot seem to find it so im asking **you** how to do it

Comment: Im sorry it's my first time on this website.

Comment: Please read the the [ask] page for info how to improve your question. It's a good idea to include the attempts you've made or even possible solutions you found that did not work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a Batch File to Open task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815111/using-a-batch-file-to-open-task-manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to display a list of processes from the command prompt you can use `TaskList.exe` if you are looking to just open the windows Task Manager you can use `TaskMgr.exe`

For standard batch file you would just use `tasklist.exe`. If you were using powershell you would use `start-process tasklist.exe -nonewwindow`.

Comment: So would i be using a line of code like this? `start process TaskList.exe`

Comment: For standard batch file you would just use `tasklist.exe`.  If you were using powershell you would use `start-process tasklist.exe -nonewwindow`

Answer (score 1):

I created a batch file to start several programs, including Task Manager.  I used this code:

cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

start taskmgr

if this path does not work for you, right click on the task manager app and look at the path in the "properties"

Answer (score 0):

```
start taskmgr
```

should work :)
(tested, it works!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with a batch file: `start "" TaskMgr.exe`

I tried it on Windows 11, it worked fine.